# How can I integrate Scikit learn models with TFX tensorflow 2.x?

Tags: scikit-learn, tensorflow2.0, tfx

I am looking for a solution to integrate scikit learn models, XGBoost models, stats models with TFX solution for end to end production use.
How can keep using scikit-learn feature along with tensorflow 2.x TFX support ?

Comment: As per this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/tree/master/tfx/examples/penguin/experimental) `TFX` support for `sklearn` is still experimental and you can also take a look at this [similar issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/issues/205) raised in TFX repo for more details on the same question. Thanks!